# Optaplanner at least one occurency constraint

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to implement a constraint so that if an element with a specific name is not assigned at least one time, the solution is penalized.

I tried using `GroupBy()` but it does not work:

```java
Constraint atLeastOne(ConstraintFactory cf) {
        return cf
                .forEach(Element.class)
                .groupBy(Element::getName, ConstraintCollectors.countDistinct())
                .filter((elementName, count) -> elementName == "foo" && count < 1)
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("At least one occurency");
    }
```

My idea is that if no element with name "foo" is present the filter does not return anything and as a consequnce the costraint is not enforced.

I also tried using `ifNotExists()`:

```java
Constraint atLeastOne(ConstraintFactory cf) {
        return cf
                .forEach(Element.class)
                .ifNotExists(Element.class, Joiners.filtering((a, b) -> a.getName() == "foo" && b.getName() == "foo"))
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("At least one occurency");
    }
```

The problem is that using `ifNotExists()` also penalizes all the elements with `a.getName() != "foo"`

Any idea to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In constraint streams, a `groupby()` only produce a result if it has at least one input tuple. This means "have at least X" constraints must be implemented as two separate constraints:

- One constraint to penalize the case when no elements satisfy the constraint
- One constraint to penalize the case when some (but not enough) elements satisfy the constraint (this is not needed since minimum is 1, but would be needed if minimum was 2 or more)

Since you are using a grouping key, you need a way to access all possible keys for the "no elements satisfy the constraint" case. Create an `ElementName` collection with all possible name and put it as a `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` on your `@PlanningSolution`. Then the constraint would look like this:

```java
Constraint atLeastOne(ConstraintFactory cf) {
    return cf
            .forEach(ElementName.class)
            .filter(elementName -> elementName.getName().equals("foo"))
            .ifNotExists(Element.class, Joiners.equal(ElementName::getName, Element::getName))
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
            .asConstraint("At least one occurency");
}
```